# mysql - Dynamic column alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have "sql query" to see number of the job done for each member in the last week so I create "sql query" and it is work very will but I want to change the alise from **week1 or week2** to **the data of this week** my "sql query" is :

```
SELECT `staffID`,  
 SUM(if (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW(), 1,0)) 
 AS `week1`, 
 SUM(if (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1,0)) 
 AS `week2`, 
FROM tasks 
WHERE status ='done'
GROUP BY `staffID
```

and I want to become like this "sql query",but mysql give me error. So, is there anyway to solve the problem?

```
SELECT `staffID`,  
 SUM(if (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW(), 1,0)) 
 AS NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 
 SUM(if (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1,0)) 
 AS NOW()-INTERVAL 2 WEEK, 
FROM tasks 
WHERE status ='done'
GROUP BY `staffID
```

sql give me this message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK

Comment: Explain what problem are you getting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is simple: It is not possible in SQL. Column aliases are constants. You would have to create the query dynamically to achieve what you want:

```
SET @column_alias1 := NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
SET @column_alias2 := NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK;
SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT SUM(...) AS `', @column_alias1, '`, SUM(...) AS `', @column_alias2, '` FROM ...');
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
```

Comment: Just a thought, how would you suggest a solution for this same problem but with high number of columns?

Comment: @YehCheez: I've never had this problem myself, because I use SQL for what it is: a language to give me data. If I want to display information in a column header in my app or website, I don't change the query, but use the programming language at hand (C#, PHP, whatever). In the rare case that I must create a query dynamically, I also do this in my app with the help of loops, if/then/else, and whatever else my programming language offers to ease the job.

Comment: That makes sense. The programming language can handle these things better than SQL.

Comment: Also keep in mind that this methods can be prone to SQL injections also..  The only save method against SQL injections is using the syntax `EXECUTE <statement> USING @<variable>`

Answer (score -1):

Check whether it works.

Added bracket to column name.

```
SELECT `staffID`,  
SUM(if (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW(), 1,0)) 
AS (SELECT NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 
SUM(if (created_at BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND NOW()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1,0)) 
AS (SELECT  NOW()-INTERVAL 2 WEEK), 
FROM tasks where status ='done'
GROUP BY `staffID
```

Comment: Checket it now, added select keyword.

Comment: still the same problem