# MySQL: Under what circumstances can you embed Sub queries?

Tags: mysql, subquery

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
SELECT IF(Index_Number = '1', Int), NULL) AS HUY,
FROM Database.Table;
```

The actual query that I'm working is much larger, but I think it will scale appropriately. In short, I'm trying to construct a query that will be as easy as possible to use in the future, and one of those modifications would be to take the `AS` clause and substitute a subquery into it, looking like this:

```
(SELECT Name FROM Database.Table WHERE Index_Number = '1')
```

With the entire code lookling like this:

```
SELECT IF(Index_Number = '1', Int), NULL) AS (SELECT Name FROM Database.Table WHERE Index_Number = '1'),
FROM Database.Table;
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error, which only occurs after I introduced the subquery. I'm wondering if this syntax error is being caused by my attempts to embed a subquery within the AS clause.

I have two questions:

1. Can you embed a subquery within an `AS`clause?
2. Under what circumstances/clauses can you embed subqueries?

Comment: You need dynamic sql to make column name variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql - Dynamic column alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795844/mysql-dynamic-column-alias)

Comment: show  the beast so we can examine it. Basically you are hiding it